# Changing group in FileZilla

Tags: macos, sftp, filezilla

Is there a way for users to change the group on files they have ownership of in FileZilla? Something equivalent to `chgrp` from the command line? And is there a way to set default groups in FileZilla? Protocol: sftp.

**FileZilla Client**

Version: 3.9.0.5

Operating system:

- Name: Mac OS X (Darwin 13.4.0 x86_64)
- Version: 10.9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FileZilla does not support changing ownership.

The SFTP technically supports it, though with the SFTP version 3 (that FileZilla supports), it's possible using GUID only (numerical value), not using group name. What is not very user-friendly. FileZilla does not make use of this protocol capability anyway. Also, it's worth noting that the most widespread SFTP server, the OpenSSH, suffers the same limitation.

So you may be able to find an SFTP client that allows changing ownership, but most probably using numerical value only.

WinSCP for instance, can change ownership using both numerical value and group name (for SFTP servers supporting version 4 and newer).
See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_properties
WinSCP is Windows application. But you can run it on OSX under Wine.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Just for completeness: The FTP protocol does not have a standard way to change the ownership either. But some FTP servers allows changing the ownership using the `SITE` command, e.g. `SITE CHGRP`. You can enter that command in FileZilla manually using the *Server > Enter custom command*.

Comment: Well, I have literally just this minute downloaded WinSCP because FileZilla does not do this, and I have to say even within the first 5 minutes of using it what a great program it is.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Yes,

Once you connect right click on a file on the lower right subpanel
and select File Permissions. Set the properties in the popup window that
pops up and click OK.

Comment: When I right click on the file with the incorrect group, I don't see a Properties option. Here's what I see on the pop-up menu: "Download, Add files to queue, View/Edit, Create directory, Create directory and enter it, Create new file, Refresh, Delete, Rename, Copy URl(s) to clipboard, File permissions..."

Comment: There's indeed no *Properties* command in FileZilla, only *File Permissions*.

Comment: Sorry, I've overlooked the name of the menu entry. Updated my answer accordingly.